Why is WebDataBinder used when Jackson is/should be used for deserialization (which breaks correct order of validation/authorization)?
My original requirement is that I want to use @EnableMethodSecurity, but when I call @RestController method with invalid payload and user missing required role, the validation takes precedence. So instead of getting 403/401 I'm getting 400 revealing something about unauthorized endpoint. That's incorrect.
I found out, that in my case it's because validation isn't part of AOP proxy chain, but it's triggered by org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod#invokeForRequest inside depths of call getMethodArgumentValues.
The workaround(well if it's even workaround) here is straightforward. Disable the validator for WebDataBinder and annotate the controller with @Validated. Doing so the binder won't throw MethodArgumentNotValidException and bean validation will be called correctly by spring in response to processing annotation @Validated.
My first question is: 1. why is WebDataBinder even used if I'm using jackson library for deserialization? Or am I? Well at least I'd like to and expect it to be used. Is there some mistake? I don't know if it's correct, I think I saw some notice, that it should not be used...
minimal working example(check master branch)
Excerpts from MWE(I can publish it later, I'm missing some tests yet):
Controller class:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/someController")
public class SomeController {

    //    @RolesAllowed(ROLE1)
    @RolesAllowed(ROLE2)
    @PostMapping("search")
    public String contactSearch(@Valid @RequestBody SearchRequest searchRequest) {
        return "OK";
    }

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class SearchRequest {

        @NotNull
        @PositiveOrZero
        private Long userId;

    }

app/security definition:
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class IsWebBinderUsedToBindJacksonDtoRequestBodyApplication {

    public static final String ROLE1 = "ROLE1";
    public static final String ROLE2 = "ROLE2";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IsWebBinderUsedToBindJacksonDtoRequestBodyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        // Define an in-memory user with roles
        UserDetails user1 = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user1")
                .password("password")
                .roles(ROLE1)
                .build();

        UserDetails user2 = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user2")
                .password("password")
                .roles(ROLE2)
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user1, user2);
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(a -> a.anyRequest().permitAll())
                .httpBasic(conf -> conf.realmName("aaa"))
                .build();
    }
}

disabling of validation can be done using:
@InitBinder
public void initUserBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    //no validation whatsoever!
    binder.setExcludedValidators(e->true);
}

and I have the second question about this @InitBinder. If there isn't better way and I have to use this, how do I configure WebDataBinder globally to disable the validator as shown (or provide some benevolet Validator implementation, or to do any other customization)? I kinda cannot find the solution for springboot 3.

Data binder isn't used so doing this will not work. The problem is that you are using annotations for security, which are handled by an interceptor. This interceptor will only kick in when the method is actually called. The method calling is only happening after the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter has prepared the method call, including the validation. If you don't want this you will need to manually validate. You can do this by injecting the validator and call validate on it. Also @Validated serves a different purpose and you will get different exceptions.

Thanks for answer. How can I verify, that Data binder isn't used? Or what does it mean? Because I can put the breakpoint there and it will be hit. I can do the workaround(disabling validator in binder) I described and it will fix the situation: I will get 401/403 for unathorized requests and 400 for authorized, invalid ones. ~  if it's not used, as you say, I'd expect say this: org.springframework.validation.DataBinder#getValidatorsToApply isn't hit. But it is, which is why my workaround works. Am I missing something about how that binder should/should not be used? I posted almost all code.

Define being used. It is only being used to do some configuration for the handle rmethod invocation it isn't used for (de)serialization. While it might appear it works @Validated on the method will lead to an additional proxy being created for your controller which will use the MethodValidationInterceptor for validation. Due to this validation will occur first and disable the validation build into Spring MVC. It will throw ConstraintViolation exceptions which will be translated by Spring Boots exception handler so you don't notice the difference.

As I see it: Being used to do X == being part of process to do X. It's hit, it's used. But IIUC what you are saying: it's not used for deserialization process as main player, but it's used to do something unimportant in whole process, and it's exptected to be hit. ~ In problem at hand it calls validation of input before security proxy, causing incorrect(subjective; /unwanted) result. So tricking 'unused' binder to not validate inputs, and use @Validated to instate MethodValidationInterceptor to the bean validation instead, is valid move. So IIUC,answer for Q1 is: it's expected behavior.

if ^^ is true, please how can I do that binder.setExcludedValidators(e->true); globally? As I don't want to specify @InitBinder in every controller or create hierarchy. If that binder has to be there, OK, but I don't want it to do any validation before security interceptor runs.

I'm not sure if this behavior is intentional or not, or whether the binder should be used or not in this case. But I saw several threads asking for fixing this without any response, so I will add my here.
The cause of problem is binder calling the validation of input data before calling authorization proxy for method level validation( here:  org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod#invokeForRequest), as demonstrated in minimal working example.
One possible solution is to use @Validated to enable spring validation using AOP proxy and either disable binder validation using @InitBinder or globally using advice:
@ControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public final class BinderShouldNotValidateAdvice {

    //global disabling data binder premature validation
    @InitBinder
    public void initUserBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        // customization specific to binding a User
        binder.setExcludedValidators(e->true);
    }

}

It does not seem, that spring handles ConstraintViolationException automatically. It will fail producing stacktrace to log and http 500 in response without failure description. So you need to implement your own exception handler as shown in MWE as well.
This is just one potential solution, if someone know better one, please let me know. Thank you!
